# How to bind the parameters separately Neo4jPHP

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher, neo4jphp

I am new to Neo4j, I am using Everyman Neo4jPhp. I have the following situation

```
foreach($id as user_id)
{
$query="match (u:user{id:{user_id}})-[r:likes]->(b:product)
        return b";
$result = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $query,array('user_id' => $user_id));
$data= $result->getResultSet(); 
}
```

I have to bind the parameters separately from loading the query.In the above code you will find the   `$result` variable where I bind the parameters and load the query in one statement, I want binding the parameters to be done in a separate statement. Just like the prepared statement in mysql. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of neo4jphp, yet.